# Backbone Marionette - how to set default routing for site

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to set default routing for site.

Reason I do this, I want to direct to page not found (page 404) if user typing wrong link or that link user typing not match in routing defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 #not found
    '*notFound' : 'notFound'
```

This have to be within last router object if there are multiple route objects and have be the last route option of that route object. Otherwise this will redirect all pages below this('*notFound': 'notFound') to 'notFound'.

Comment: Welcome, Keep in touch, if there's anything on the go with js. Cheers

Comment: This do not seems to work